# Firebase do i get charged if i load a node with a url from storage but I don't load image on the UI?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am wondering if for the firebase realtime database, if I load a node that has for example a title, caption and image url (Cloud Storage url) - If i query and fetch the node but only display the title and caption on the UI, will I still be getting charged for the Cloud Storage Image Download?

If so I will have to re-structure my DB.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL is just a string.  It doesn't do anything if you don't actually take action to download it. If there is no download, there is no billing for egress.